# if a value is equal to an object's key in an array of objects, return that object's value javasciprt

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, key

I have this array of objects:

```
myArray=[
{name: 'joe', value: 'joe rogan'},
{name: 'sarah', value: 'sarah rogan'},
{name: 'jack', value: 'jack rogan'},
{name: 'steph', value: 'steph rogan'}
]
```

I wanna see if `myArray`'s names include `'sarah'` then return its value which is `'sarah rogan'`.
I have tried:

```
const myName = myArray.map(o => o.name === 'sarah' ? o.value : "")
```

But it returns an array with two values. How can I just get `'sarah'`'s value which is `'sarah rogan'` as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const myName = myArray.find(x => x.name === 'sarah').value
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const myArray=[
  {name: 'joe', value: 'joe rogan'},
  {name: 'sarah', value: 'sarah rogan'},
  {name: 'jack', value: 'jack rogan'},
  {name: 'steph', value: 'steph rogan'}
];
let obj = myArray.find(({name})=>name==='sarah');
if(obj) console.log(obj.value);
```

Comment: Now you have a gold badge you should use it to hammer these duplicates...

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates? Is this a repeat question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as well. This will return all matches as an `Array` unlike `find` which returns the first match.

```js
myArray=[
{name: 'joe', value: 'joe rogan'},
{name: 'sarah', value: 'sarah rogan'},
{name: 'jack', value: 'jack rogan'},
{name: 'steph', value: 'steph rogan'}
]

// filter the array and get the first item
const myName = myArray.filter(o => o.name === 'sarah')[0]

console.log(myName.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a for loop:

```js
myArray=[
{name: 'joe', value: 'joe rogan'},
{name: 'sarah', value: 'sarah rogan'},
{name: 'jack', value: 'jack rogan'},
{name: 'steph', value: 'steph rogan'}
]
```

```js
for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    if(myArray[i].name === 'sarah'){
        console.log(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```